Packaging executable file as a ElectronNet app
I have a electronNet project. it runs well. But one issue is when running the app, it fails to locate some .dll files that i need to run some specific tasks.
So what i did was build my dotnet core app and frontend app and added a command to move all build files to a folder called result.
In this result folder i have the .exe and required dll files. i can run my app by double cliking my .exe and it opens the app in the browser and all works well.
But I need to package it as a Electron app. How can i do this?
FYI: my results folder is not a solution/project. when i run electronize build /target win it says this is not a project.
Can someone point me in the right direction on how can i get my executable to package as a electron app.
I tried updating electron.manifest.json file to point for executable file which is in my results folder. but when i try to run the app, i get a error saying it cannot locate my .exe file.
Here is my manifest file
{
  "executable": "App.Server",
  "name": "App.Server",
  "author": "",
  "singleInstance": false,
  "environment": "Production",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.App.Server.app",
    "productName": "App Name",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2024",
    "buildVersion": "1.0",
    "compression": "maximum",
    "directories": {
      "output": "../../../bin/Desktop"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "../../../assets/icons/app-icon-win.ico",
      "target": ["nsis"],
      "artifactName": "appName${version}Setup.exe"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "../../../assets/icons/app-icon-win.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "../../../assets/icons/app-icon-win.ico",
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true
    },
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./bin",
        "to": "bin",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      }
    ],
    "files": [
      {
        "from": "./ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
        "to": "ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      },
      "**/*"
    ]
  },
  "aspCoreBackendPort": 5000
}
 

